# $R/I\cong R/\text{Ann}_R(R/I)$ but $I\neq\text{Ann}_R(R/I)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Most of my experience with rings is with commutative rings, so I lack some intuition about the nature of noncommutative rings. Does there exist a noncommutative unital ring $R$ and left ideal $I$ such that $R/I\cong R/\text{Ann}_R(R/I)$ as left $R$-modules but $I\neq \text{Ann}_R(R/I)$? I suspect that such an $R$ and $I$ do exist but are awkward to construct. Note that

$$\text{Ann}_R(R/I)=\{r\in R:\forall x\in R,\ rx\in I\}\subseteq I$$

and that $\text{Ann}_R(R/I)$ is always a two-sided ideal. As such, if $I$ is not two-sided then we already get $I\neq \text{Ann}_R(R/I)$. There is also a surjection $\pi:R/\text{Ann}_R(R/I)\to R/I$ induced by canonical surjection $R\to R/I$, but this induced map obviously won't be an isomorphism when $I\neq \text{Ann}_R(R/I)$. Any ideas would be appreciated.

My question is equivalent to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878020/example-of-ring-r-with-ideals-i-neq-j-such-that-r-i-cong-r-j-as-modules) with the additional constraint that $J$ must be two-sided.

Comment: I have posted this question to Math Overflow. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371978/r-i-cong-r-textann-rr-i-but-i-neq-textann-rr-i